# Issue while inserting Data in Firestore using cloud workflows firestore connector with Json object coming from previous step which is a cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-filestore, google-workflows

I am trying to build a workflow where in step1 I am running a cloud function which returns a Json Object in the form of python dictionary and I want the same to be inserted in Firestore using firestore connector. But I am getting the below error:

```
    HTTP server responded with error code 400
    in step "create_document", routine "main", line: 27
    HTTP server responded with error code 400
    in step "create_document", routine "main", line: 28
    {
      "body": {
        "error": {
          "code": 400,
          "details": [
            {
              "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
              "fieldViolations": [
                {
                  "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"field1\" at 'document.fields[0].value': Cannot find field.",
                  "field": "document.fields[0].value"
                },
                {
                  "description": "Invalid value at 'document.fields[1].value' (type.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Value), 200",
                  "field": "document.fields[1].value"
                },
                {
                  "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"Alt-Svc\" at 'document.fields[2].value': Cannot find field.",
                  "field": "document.fields[2].value"
                },
                {
                  "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"Cache-Control\" at 'document.fields[2].value': Cannot find field.",
                  "field": "document.fields[2].value"
                },
                {
                  "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"Content-Length\" at 'document.fields[2].value': Cannot find field.",
                  "field": "document.fields[2].value"
                },
                {
                  "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"Content-Type\" at 'document.fields[2].value': Cannot find field.",
                  "field": "document.fields[2].value"
                },
                {
                  "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"Date\" at 'document.fields[2].value': Cannot find field.",
                  "field": "document.fields[2].value"
                }
```

This is how my workflow looks like

```
main:
    params: [args]
    steps:
        - step1:
            call: http.get
            args:
                url: https://XXXXXXXXXXXXX.cloudfunctions.net/step1-workflow
                query:
                    bucket_name: ${args.bucket_name}
                    blob_name: ${args.blob_name}
            result: key_val
        - step2:
            assign:
                - project_id: ${sys.get_env("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID")}
                - collection: "a-dummy-collection"
                - document: "new7-dummy-document"
        - create_document:
            call: googleapis.firestore.v1.projects.databases.documents.createDocument
            args:
                collectionId: ${collection}
                parent: ${"projects/" + project_id + "/databases/(default)/documents"}
                query: 
                    documentId: ${document}
                body: 
                    fields: ${key_val}
            result: inserted
```

if in place of ${key_val} I use simple json {"field1": {"stringValue": "str1"},"field2": {"integerValue": 10}} it works fine and data gets inserted in the Firestore but if I try to use the object from variable ${key_val} which is in the same structure as mentioned json it gives error.

Comment: Could you please show exactly what `${key_val}` looks like? I suspect it's not the normal input that Firestore expects.

Comment: I think instead of `${key_val}` you should use `${key_val.body}`. The errors you get mention fields like `content-type`, etc, which seem to be the HTTP response (with its headers, etc), not the actual body of the response (ie. the JSON document you returned from your function)

Comment: Thanks @glaforge, it is working with ${key_val.body}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer given in the comments: the `${key_val}` result from the call to the cloud function is actually returning the whole response object, not just the body. That's why in the error messages, you were seeing things like `content-type` and other headers.

The solution here is to say that we want the body of that response with: `${key_val.body}`.